# Kubernetes Ingress path: allow all exept for /blog/

Tags: kubernetes, microservices, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I have a service running on Kubernetes available on a domain like `example.com`. I'm trying to add a path which should redirect to a wordpress blog. So I need to add a rule: everithing that goes in /blog/ should redirect to wordpress, otherwise use the main app.

I tried to include a regexp for the main application path to include all except /blog/

```
  - host: example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /^(?!blog).*$
```

but I keep getting `must be a valid regex` or if I remove the slash, it says `must be an absolute path`. I can't seem to find a way how to do that, it just keeps redirecting to my root app

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: app
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
spec:
  rules:
  - host: example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: MainAppService
          servicePort: 3010
      - path: /blog/*
        backend:
          serviceName: BlogService
          servicePort: 3020
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this -

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
  name: app
spec:
  rules:
  - host: example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /(.*)
        backend:
          serviceName: MainAppService
          servicePort: 3010
      - path: /blog/(.*)
        backend: 
          serviceName: BlogService
          servicePort: 3020
```

---

I guess, this should work

Comment: I had some issues figuring out the rewrite-target part, but this actually works!